# Executing a perl script in bash, need to parse it's JSON output and put it into a variable

Tags: bash, perl

I have an automation script that I'm writing in Bash. I need to execute a perl script from within this and capture/parse one specific part of it's output and use it as a variable in order to complete the bash script's tasks.

For example:

```
echo "Creating database for "$custname
perl /home/dib/testing/addCustomer.cgi name=$custname prefix=$customerno
```

The perl script "addCustomer.cgi" will return JSON output of:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
   "recordcount" : 1,
   "status" : "OK",
   "statusText" : "Add Customer: 40:Testing",
   "customer" : [
      {
         "address" : "",
         "city" : "",
         "country" : "US",
         "description" : "",
         "email" : "",
         "endDate" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "frontendurl" : "",
         "phone" : "",
         "prefix" : "testing",
         "startDate" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "state" : "",
         "customerID" : "40",
         "subscriberName" : "Testing",
         "url" : "",
         "zip" : ""
      }
   ],
   "timestamp" : 1559163419
}
```

What I need to capture is the customerID number, stick it into a variable, and use it to finish the bash script. Is something like this possible? I always see parsing or passing from bash to perl but not the other way around.

Comment: Can't you modify the Perl script to return just the id instead of the full json?

Comment: "_modify the Perl script to return just the id_" -- or add to it a command-line option for that

Comment: @zdim: Yes, that's the best way how to modify it :)

Comment: @choroba no, I can't modify the perl script. I'm just trying to automate a process that currently requires executing the script, noting the value of customerID, then using that with a different command to complete the task.

Comment: As perl is already installed, you can pipe the output to `perl -MJSON::PP -0777 -ne 's/^.*$//m; print decode_json($_)->{customer}[0]{customerID}'`.

Answer (score 1):

Append this to your Perl command:

```
| sed 1d | jq -r '.customer[].customerID'
```

Output:

```
40
```

I assume there's one header line.

Comment: You'll need the `jq` command for this but it is an incredible tool if you do a lot of JSON work, so a must-have and worth installing.

Comment: This works to get the value I need, but I still need to stick that value into a variable.

Comment: Try this: `variable=$(perl ... | sed ... | jq ...)`